# Failed to read SERVERPROPERTY

Tags: sql-server

The stored procedure has MSSQL server version checking using the SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') property. Depending on what this property returns, the dynamic script is executed appropriately for the installed version.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @version NVARCHAR(128) = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR)
SET @version = SUBSTRING(@version, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @version) - 1)

DECLARE @versionAsInt INT = CAST(@version AS INT)

IF @versionAsInt > 10 
    SET @query = 'SELECT 1'
ELSE 
    SET @query = 'SELECT 2'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

But sometimes this check fails and code that doesn't match the installed version is executed, resulting in errors. Usually at this time the server is very heavily overloaded.

I haven't found any information that this property is a problem, but everything indicates that this property can sometimes return null.
Has anyone encountered this problem before and can provide a link to it?

Comment: This shouldn't ever work, because the four-part version string that `SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')`  returns can't be cast to an integer. I think you may have oversimplified a bit.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I wrote that I simplified the script. Of course it won't work.

Comment: Simplified code ideally is still working code, so it's representative of the actual problem, which is why we like a [mre]. Otherwise people can expend quite a bit of fruitless effort investigating things that turn out to be completely unrelated. If you literally have `CAST(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR) AS INT) > 10` in your code, the problem would be that this always fails; if that's not what you have in your code, post what you do have.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, corrected the script

Comment: Although I don't expect it would solve a load problem (if it is one), the check could be simplified to `CONVERT(INT, SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion')) > 10`. `ProductMajorVersion` was introduced in SQL Server 2012, which happens to also be what this checks for, so the fact that it returns nothing on SQL Server 2008 is no problem. Note also that both SQL Server 2012 and 2008 are completely unsupported by now, so the check may be unnecessary in the sense that you hopefully aren't running 2008 at all anymore, and if you are upgrading would be a great idea.

Comment: Also, given that the server version will not change during the procedure's execution, if `SERVERPROPERTY` malfunctions under load (I don't know if it does, mind you) a simple workaround would be to store it once in a table or create a table-valued inline function and use that (using a SQL Server Agent job, for example), rather than continuously querying for it. Ideally this shouldn't be necessary, of course, and I have a hard time imagining something that essentially reads a constant to have load problems so I'd first look at other causes, but stranger things have happened.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, We unfortunately do not have the opportunity to update the server, because. we don't have access to it. That's why the stored procedure has this condition.